# Power of Giants Orc bloodline (Sp) - Why doesn't it go to form II?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, bloodline, orc

The question is specifically about the [Orc Bloodine](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/orc-bloodline). At level 15, you get a free "Giant Form I" spell:

> Power of Giants (Sp): At 15th level, you may grow to Large size as a
>   standard action. At this size you gain a +6 size bonus to Strength, a
>   –2 penalty to Dexterity, a +4 size bonus to Constitution, and a +4
>   natural armor bonus. You may return to your normal size as a standard
>   action. You may remain in this size for up to 1 minute per character
>   level per day; this duration does not need to be consecutive, but it
>   must be used in 1 minute increments.

This is cool and exactly the kind of hulk-like sorcerer build I'm going for. *However*, there is clearly a better version at *just the next spell level* called "Giant Form II". The only difference I see is how you can turn it on and off at will and save the minutes, and doesn't need a material. Why doesn't it upgrade to form II at some point?

Do you think it's fair that I "upgrade" this power to the second version if I take Giant Form II as a sorcerer learned spell? I'm not trying to be overpowered, I'm trying to get use out of my bloodline power for more than just a few levels. In fact, I'll have the Giant Form II spell either way.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spell [*giant form I*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/g/giant-form-i) is usually available initially to a level 14 [sorcerer](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer). And, at that point, the sorcerer can cast it four times per day. But a Sor14 doesn't need *giant form I* four times per day for 14 min./day. Encounters don't last that long. Most of the time in combat, after the first minute (or, more likely, after the first 3 rounds) that extra duration will be wasted.

However, being able to use the spell-like ability *power of giants* 15 times per day for 1 min. each use is *far* more convenient, freeing up a precious high-level spell known even if the spell-like ability becomes available after the spell *giant form I*. Further, the sorcerer can activate the spell-like ability—instead of spending a high-level spell slot—as a buff prior to combat pretty much *whenever he wants* (15 uses per day is *a lot*). That's pretty serious, too.

I can't know what the developers were thinking, but my guess is that the special ability doesn't advance to *power of the even gianter* or something because the sorcerer *already* has *this* ability and, rather than give the sorcerer something a *little* better than what he already has at level 20, the developers gave the [orc bloodline](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/sorcerer/bloodlines/bloodlines-from-paizo/orc-bloodline) something brand new.

You can *ask* the DM if you can upgrade the spell-like ability *power of giants* contingent upon taking as a spell known the spell *giant form II* at level 16. I mean, that's *interesting*, but I wouldn't count on the DM agreeing to it. The spell *giant form II* is an 8th-level spell, and those matter even at level 20. Being able to cast an 8th-level spell 16 to 20 times—even with a 1 min. duration instead of a 20 min. duration—might be viewed as excessive.

Comment: Thanks, very enlightening. This all makes total sense now, especially on the prebuff and not wasting spells. Only thing that bothers me still is that if I want to min/max my hulk-like sorcerer, I need Giant Form II. I'll see what I can trade off to achieve that and still keep the bloodline power flavor if the DM thinks it's ok.